# how to watch changes on hidden fields with Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have dropdown made from divs. It's not my doing, is from external agency. But this is not important. The div with a dropdown looks like this:

```html
<label class='label-block' for='kraj-dokument'>Kraj wydania dokumentu tożsamości *</label>
                    <input type='hidden' name='kraj-dokument' id='kraj-dokument' value="" drop-down-validation-directive /> <div class="select kraj-dokument" data-destination="kraj-dokument">
                        <p class="label">Wybierz z listy</p>
                        <div class="options">
                            <p class="option" data-ng-repeat="country in countries">{{country.Name}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

When you click on a choice in this dropdown an external javascript is adding th the hidden field attribute called value and it insert a text from the choise to that value. As you can see I have a directive on that hidden inputu which looks like this (after several searches, and everything):

```js
myapp.directive("dropDownValidationDirective", function () {
return  function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
    scope.$watch(attr['value'], function(nv) {
            elem.val(nv);
        }
        );
}
```

});

The problem is when I'm doing watch nothing happens, the value is not geting watched although the change is seen when debuging this in chrome. By the way. I'm trying to also do a validation on this dropdowwn. My idea was to check if this value is filled or not and tell to the user to fill the dropdown by adding a class to it wich marks this thing red. Is that the way to do it?

**UPDATE** I forgot to add, and I think this is also important that the click event on that div is done with the mentioned external javascript. I'm pasting it below. I've put the external javascript functionality into the service:

```js
myApp.service('DropDownService', function () {
this.renderDropDown = function () {
    function initEvents() {
        var selectClicked = $(".selectClicked");
        $(".select").each(function () {
            var destination = $(this).attr("data-destination");
            var option = $(this).find(".option");
            var options = $(this).find(".options");
            var label = $(this).find(".label");
            var select = $(this);

            label.click(function () {
                if (label.hasClass("clicked")) {
                    $(".select .options").hide();
                    $(".select .label").removeClass("clicked");
                    $(".select").removeClass("clicked");
                    selectClicked.removeClass("clicked");
                } else {
                    $(".select .label").removeClass("clicked");
                    $(".select").removeClass("clicked");
                    label.addClass("clicked");
                    select.addClass("clicked");
                    selectClicked.addClass("clicked");
                    $(".select .options").hide();
                    options.show();
                }
            });

            option.unbind("click").bind("click", function () {
                $("#" + destination).attr("value", $(this).text());
                label.text($(this).text());
                options.hide();                    
                $(".select .label").removeClass("clicked");
                $(".select").removeClass("clicked");
                $(".select").removeClass("error");
                selectClicked.removeClass("clicked");
            });
        });
    }

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {

        initEvents();


        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") !== -1) {
            $('body').addClass("MacOS");
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Do You can to change anything on your input hidden? If yes, you can to create a simple directive. But you can use other simple approach: change to input text, with ng-model, and uses a css to hide the field.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking about that to, but the question is, when the external javascript will set the value of that hidden inputm will it update the model?

Comment: if the input is "text", the angular detects any changes, I used it before. But I prefer the @kozlice soluction

Comment: yeah, that one worked for me :) thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use interpolation & attrs.$observe instead:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
    <label class="label-block" for="kraj-dokument">Kraj wydania dokumentu tożsamości *</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="kraj-dokument" id="kraj-dokument" value="{{ TotalPrice }}" drop-down-validation-directive />
    <div class="select kraj-dokument" data-destination="kraj-dokument" ng-click="AddItem()">
        Click to change and see console output
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})
app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.Quantity = 0;
    $scope.TotalPrice = 0;
    $scope.Price = 100;
    $scope.AddItem = function() {
        $scope.Quantity++;
        $scope.TotalPrice = $scope.Price * $scope.Quantity;
    };
});
app.directive("dropDownValidationDirective", function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            attrs.$observe('value', function(nv) {
                console.log(nv);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ghd9c8q3/56/

Comment: I think I've tried the observe but I will try this again. I will try your soultion with total price, but I don't know if exterrnal javascript will add the value field the TotalPrice let's say in your case will do the job I hope so because I'm running out of ideas. Any way if this works how to validate such construction? I have a css class error that surrounds this strange dropdown wit red lines and I want angular validation to respond to that

Comment: I've added also the contents of my dropdown service where I've put the external javascript functionality

Comment: It works, your concept :) Thanks !! :) now what's left is the validation ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the way you're doing things is the best way, but I know why your watch doesn't do anything.

`$scope.$watch()` expects either a function, or an expression.

If you pass a function, it's called at each digest loop and its result is the value passed to the change listener.

If you pass an expression, it's evaluated on the scope, and the result of the evaluation is the value passed to the change listener.

So what you actually need is:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return attr['value'];
}, function(nv) {
    elem.val(nv);
});
```

Comment: Ive tried that, but the watch did not work, as I said, I've tried everything what google gave me and this was one of the ways, and when the external javascript is adding the value to the hidden field nothing happens